# How does "Buying an email domain" work?

Tags: email

When you buy a web domain you basically link an IP address with a more human readable address (from **82.82.82.82** to **[www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)**) and you can host at that IP address a web server (with Tomcat for example). This is a more raw/basic explanation.

But if I buy a domain for email from [Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/hosting/email/), for each plan it says X GB for emails (also it does say hosting email service). Does this mean that I don't need a server "to host the email", and that I'm using their servers for sending, receiving and storing emails? Or how does this "Buying email domain" work?

Also, if you create a **Google Workspace** account, there you have the option to use your own domain. How does this work in relation to sending, receiving and storing emails? Will it then use google servers, or google will be a link to another server?

This might seem a simple thing to most enthusiasts, but I never had to deal with email domains until now, and for me it seems quite a bit different then web domain where the user just need to know "where to go" and he will then get an web page, while with email you need to know where to send, but you also need a server to store the email and handle sending and receiving.

Comment: You don't buy a web domain, you buy a domain. You can then use that domain to host a web server, a mail server, or anything else. The Namecheap link you are referring to is not about "buying a domain name" (although they also offer that service), it's about mail hosting.

Comment: "Also" (although you shouldn't ask more than one question at a time), Google Workspace is also, among other things, a mail hosting service.

Comment: Let me see if I get this right, and to make it simpler let's take Namecheap as example. If I go there and buy a domain (mydomain.com), I can then use that domain to link my IP to host on my local PC a web server (www.mydomain.com), but I can also use that domain to create an account on Google Workspace, which will host an email server for @mydomain.com, and in google example, I can have up to 30 email aliases, as in support@mydomian.com / pr@mydomian.com / hr@mydomian.com .... using the domain I bought from Namecheap? Or any other hosting service for email then google.

Comment: If this is the case, then yeah, there are more then 1 questions, but I didn't knew how this actually work, and I thought it kinda is a single thing when it comes to email. Thank you!

Comment: Also, if I understood that right, then make your comment as an answer and say what an domain actually is and what you can do with it, to mark it as the solution. I truly thought that when you buy a domain (mydomain.com) it only meant for an web server, and not that you can use that also for email for example as well, and you don't need to buy one for a web server and a separate one for emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paul mentioned, domains and email hosting are two completely different things, but they are closely connected.

A domain name can be purchased through a wide variety of companies, often referred to as Registrars (you’d be the registrant), and once you have that domain you can effectively do whatever you like with it.

Associated with the domain name are DNS records, and they’ll generally (not always, but that gets more complicated than need be) be hosted by the Registrar that currently provides the domain for you. The domain belongs to you, so you can choose down the road to transfer it to a different Registrar, after which they’ll handle things like renewals, your DNS etc instead. It’s not tied to any one company, it’s yours (for as long as you keep renewing it!).

The DNS records include things like A records pointing to websites, MX records pointing to email, and a variety of other possible services. That’s why there’s no such thing as a “web domain” or “email domain”, they can be either or more commonly both.

With things like email, the MX records tell the internet that anything @example.com should be sent to x mail server. Then the mail server handles what to do with bob@example.com, info@, sales@ etc.

You could have your domain held by one company, your email services held with another, and your website with a third, or all three at the same place. You simply get the relevant DNS records updated to point to the appropriate destinations for each service, with the provider giving you detailed instructions of what to change where.

In the specific example of Namecheap, those packages are specifically related to the email service, not to the domain name. Note near the bottom of the page in the FAQ under “How do I get a company email address?” it specifically talks about the option to purchase the domain through them, but that if your domain is currently held elsewhere you can still use it with them, eg it’s not an included part of that service but an available extra. What they don’t spell out (I imagine it’s covered in their documentation), is that if the domain was held elsewhere then you’d simply get the email related DNS records setup to point to Namecheap’s mail servers to get it to work.

Finally, you mention “use that domain to link my IP to host on my local PC a web server”. Technically yes in theory, but there are a LOT of catches which unless you’re a lot more experienced with how that kind of thing works I wouldn’t even attempt it. There are plenty of cheap web hosts available that will provide web hosting services (including many of those who provide email hosting).

Note, even this long reply is quite generalized, but hopefully it explains the concepts involved.

Comment: This is a good explanation of domains, and yes, I was missing/misunderstood a few key details about domains. Yeah I know you can get a lot deeper into this but this is all that I needed as a base/start, as for the rest now that I know this, it will be a lot easier for me. Thank you!